# Where is builtins module located?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to lookup in all the directories listed in `sys.path` but I couldn't find any `builtins.py` file, so where is it?

Comment: do you want import builtins function ?

Comment: I just want to know where they are

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Literally the module is built-in to the python interpreter.

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins
<module 'builtins' (built-in)>
>>> import sys
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Such modules are represented with `(built-in)` as you can see in the above interactive session.

If the module is loaded from file, it will be represented as follow:

```
>>> import ftplib
>>> ftplib
<module 'ftplib' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\ftplib.py'>
```

---

**UPDATE** You can find builtins module's code in [`Python/bltinmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/bltinmodule.c) from the Python source code.